# Unable to connect to tableau server 10.5 using TableauServerClient

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have used the following Python code to connect to Tableau server:

```py
import tableauserverclient as TSC
tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('username', 'password')
server = TSC.Server('https://server_name.com/')
server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 444, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1443, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1191, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 48, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]  

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 849, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 356, in connect
    ssl_context=context)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 359, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 450, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='server_name.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/2.3/auth/signin (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tableauserverclient\server\endpoint\endpoint.py", line 114, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tableauserverclient\server\endpoint\auth_endpoint.py", line 30, in sign_in
    **self.parent_srv.http_options)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 559, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 511, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='server_name.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/2.3/auth/signin (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am beginner to python and tableau, even i am facing the same problem.. Let me know if you get any solution :) @SKS

Answer (score 2):

Add this line of code...

```
server.add_http_options({'verify': False})
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution above did not work for me, however, this worked:

```
server = TSC.Server('yourURL',use_server_version=False)
server.add_http_options({'verify': False})
```

setting 'use_server_version=' to 'False' worked for me. Also, you can try to change 'https' to 'http'. Others noted that it also helped them to update their certificates: pip install python-certifi-win32